# react-native-vector-icons/Feather icons are not displayed

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, react-native-vector-icons

I have upgraded my app to RN version 0.60.5 and using `react-native-vector-icons/Feather` for icons. Before the upgrade the icons were displayed well, but after it all I see is squares instead of icons:

[image]

I use it like this:

```
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Feather';
.
.
.
 return (
   <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.btnPressed('Discover')} style={[styles.btn, { marginLeft: 20 }]}>
     <Icon name={'compass'} color={this.state.discoverSelected ? this.props.activeTintColor : this.props.inactiveTintColor} size={24} />
     <Text style={[styles.btnTxt, { color: this.state.discoverSelected ? this.props.activeTintColor : this.props.inactiveTintColor }]}>Discover</Text>
   </TouchableOpacity>
)
```

What can be the reason for this?

Comment: Have you tried `react-native link`?

Comment: yes @AbdumutalAbdusamatov

Answer (score 1):

I experienced same problem before and I solve it by following official installation documentation
by using 
[option-with-cocoapods](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons#option-with-cocoapods) for ios
and 
[option-with-gradle](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons#option-with-gradle-recommended) for android